# Generate allure report with .NET 6.0 and XUnit

Tags: unit-testing, .net-6.0, xunit, allure

I've got a C# .NET Framework 4.7.2 Project with NUnit and i generated an allure report out of it.
Now i upgraded it to .NET 6.0 with XUnit and everything works fine, exept there is no allure report generated.

I use the [Allure.XUnit](https://github.com/Tinkoff/Allure.XUnit) package to generate allure reports, it worked on another XUnit project.

After executing the tests with `dotnet test project.proj` the tests are executed, but there is no allure-results folder.

The AllureConfig.json file looks like this:

```
{
  "allure": {
    "directory": "allure-results",
    "links": [
      "{link}",
      "https://xx.jira.com/browse/{issue}"
    ]
  },
  "specflow": {
    "stepArguments": {
      "convertToParameters": "true",
      "paramNameRegex": "",
      "paramValueRegex": ""
    },
    "grouping": {
      "suites": {
        "parentSuite": "^parentSuite:?(.+)",
        "suite": "^suite:?(.+)",
        "subSuite": "^subSuite:?(.+)"
      },
      "behaviors": {
        "epic": "^epic:?(.+)",
        "feature": "^feature:?(.+)",
        "story": "^story:(.+)"
      }
    },
    "labels": {
      "owner": "^author:?(.+)",
      "severity": "^(normal|blocker|critical|minor|trivial)"
    },
    "links": {
      "tms": "^story:(.+)",
      "issue": "^issue:(.+)",
      "link": "^link:(.+)"
    }
  }
}
```

The .proj file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0-windows</TargetFramework>
    <GenerateAssemblyInfo>false</GenerateAssemblyInfo>
    <AssemblyTitle>title</AssemblyTitle>
    <Product>title</Product>
    <Copyright>Copyright ©  2023</Copyright>
    <AssemblyVersion>1.0.0.0</AssemblyVersion>
    <FileVersion>1.0.0.0</FileVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="ParameterLexicon">
      <HintPath>..\..\internal.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="allureConfig.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\..\internal\lib.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Allure.XUnit" Version="2.1.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="coverlet.collector" Version="3.2.0">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="17.6.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="MSTest.TestAdapter" Version="1.3.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="MSTest.TestFramework" Version="1.3.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="xunit" Version="2.4.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="13.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="xunit.runner.visualstudio" Version="2.4.5">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone else also get this problem:

The Problem does not exist in the provided code, the XUnit tests needed another tag...

Wrong: `[Theory]`

Right: `[AllureXunitTheory]`

Comment: I am also trying to achieve this but cannot generate the allure reports. I tried using the https://github.com/Tinkoff/Allure.XUnit NuGet package. I have the "allureConfig.json" just like yours and have used [AllureXunit] attribute for my tests. But it still isn't working. Any code that you can share to make it work?

Comment: @Anon as far as i know replacling the AllureXunit attributes with the AllureXunitTheory attribute should work.. If not please provide me some code.

Comment: I am using AllureXunit since I don't have Theory tests. Here are the additional details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76848437/not-able-to-generate-allure-reports-in-net-6-0-project-with-xunit-unit-test-fra

Comment: @Anon, well i can't help you then, all our tests are Theory tests...