# Not able to generate allure reports in .Net 6.0 project with Xunit unit test framework

Tags: c#, .net, allure, xunit.net, xunit2

I have a .Net 6 project with Xunit and I have installed the https://github.com/Tinkoff/Allure.XUnit Nuget package.

I am using the following config file for allure reports and have placed this at the root of my project. The file name is 'allureConfig.json'

```
  "allure": {
    "directory": "allure-results",
    "links": [
      "{link}",
      "https://xx.jira.com/browse/{issue}"
    ]
  }
```

I am also using the 'AllureXunit' attribute to mark the tests (instead of the 'Fact' attribute) in my project like this:

```
[AllureXunit(DisplayName = "Negative Test Case")]
public void Test1()
   {
      Steps.Step("Nested step", () => { });
      Assert.True(1 != 1);
   }
```

The test executes successfully but no 'allure-results' folder is generated.
Am I missing something for this to work?